# Is it possible to have an interface without a method in java

Tags: java

I am new to java and trying to understand interface.Making an interface without a method gives compile time error.What is the reason for this behaviour?

```
import java.io.*;
interface A{
int x=10;

}
class B implements A{


    System.out.print("i am in B and x is"+x);


}
class InterfaceEx{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a;
        a=new B();

        }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can. These are called marker interfaces. You probably have some other syntax error.

Comment: That is impossible. Can you show us your code?

Comment: Interfaces don't need to have any methods or fields. What they have is up to you... just no implementation... post the error and we can help

Comment: have a code for this?

Comment: Your `System.out.print` should come under some method.

Comment: You have to invoke System.out.print in a method. (main I suppose)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have an interface without a method in Java.  In fact, the [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interfaces are built-in to Java and don't have any methods.  They are called "marker" interfaces.

Quoting from the [Wikipedia page on marker interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern):

> Whereas a typical interface specifies functionality (in the form of
>   method declarations) that an implementing class must support, a marker
>   interface need not do so. The mere presence of such an interface
>   indicates specific behavior on the part of the implementing class.

As for why your `B` interface doesn't compile (now that you've supplied the code), you need to place your statement inside a method or constructor, such as:

```
class B implements A{
    public B() {
         System.out.print("I am in B and x is"+x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that `x` is `static final` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [java.io.Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface is the example of such marker interface

Comment: +1 `Clonable` too. Any interface that was implemented as the marker design pattern will fit the description ;)

Comment: and the Remote interface.

Answer (score 0):

According to the java Language Specification

> The body of an interface **may** declare members of the interface, that
>   is, fields (§9.3), methods (§9.4), classes (§9.5), and interfaces
>   (§9.5).

It does not say you have to so yes you can have empty interfaces

And from the above answer there are empty interfaces

Answer (score 0):

```
class B implements A{


    System.out.print("i am in B and x is"+x);


}
```

This is not legal syntax. A class definition can only have variables or methods; that's it. That code out there by itself isn't a definition of a variable or a method, so the compiler doesn't know what to make of it.

If you define a method, then that method can have any instructions inside it.

```
class B implements A{

    public void myMethod(){

        System.out.print("i am in B and x is"+x);

    }


}
```

You don't seem to understand what a class is, its a pretty fundamental concept to OOP and Java, although can be confusing at first.

**Also, pay attention to your errors.** One error is very different from another. **You assumed that this error was due to an empty interface; that was wrong. It was a syntax error. If you'd read the compiler output, it would have told you this already.** It tries to help you.

Comment: This answer is a little offensive in tone, either tone it down or delete it. Moreover your suggestion is unhelpful; the OP probably wants an instance initialisation block or a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Interface without method are known as **Marker interface**.

Marker interface is used as a tag to inform a message to the java compiler so that it can add special behavior to the class implementing it.

Example: `java.io.Serializable`, `Cloneable`